# how to set the Image in ImageView without strected with full screen in android

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin, gallery

I am using imageview to show the photo. And i am showing photo in full screen. then my photo is streched. and my imageview height is 500 and width is 300 .How to solve this task.

Comment: use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: android:scaleType="centerCrop" is not working. image is cutting from corners.Please help me

Comment: try android:scaleType="fitXY"
 or android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `scaleType` of the image view.

In xml,
`android:scaleType="centerInside"`

If center inside isn't what you want, see the other options at this link

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: When I used android:scaleType="centerInside" , then  Image is showing in center of the screen. but i want to show image in full screen without streched.